# Unit Test Case reporting for WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2, maven-surefire-plugin, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to integrate Unit Test cases in my existing wso2 code base.
Is there any way we can have a reporting structure like Surefire reports for our Unit Test Cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the plugin `synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin` in your `pom.xml`

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.27</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>synapse-unit-test</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>synapse-unit-test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <server>
      <testServerType>${testServerType}</testServerType>
      <testServerHost>${testServerHost}</testServerHost>
      <testServerPort>${testServerPort}</testServerPort>
      <testServerPath>${testServerPath}</testServerPath>
    </server>
    <testCasesFilePath>${project.basedir}/test/${testFile}</testCasesFilePath>
    <mavenTestSkip>${maven.test.skip}</mavenTestSkip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The content of the tag `<testCasesFilePath>` is the path where units tests are saved